# Using multiple jquery and javascript in html code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, optimization

I am currently designing webpage as follows

- Its with collapsible panel so I am using Accordian set
- Address Details the fields are disabled by default but when users ticks the check box all the fields in that section becomes enabled.by using javascripts
- Sibling section the table is hidden (use CSS St-yle) and then depending upon the number choosen the rows are displayed by using Jquery

Issues faced :

Only 2 javascript works (section 1 and section 3)are working  even though its identical.

My jQuery isn't working at all ( even though it works on it's own).

But after combining all of them in one go it doesn't.

Tried looking into no conflict feature but cant get it work either. Can you guys please help me in understanding where I am going wrong ?

Below is [code](https://jsfiddle.net/53nfxxdw/) I am using :

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--This is Javascript to disable the address fields if user doesn't tick the checkbox-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sccb').click(function(){
        if (this.checked) {
            $('#cns').removeAttr("disabled");
            $('#cns2').removeAttr("disabled");
            $('#cns3').removeAttr("disabled");
            $('#cns4').removeAttr("disabled");
            $('#cns5').removeAttr("disabled");
            $('#cns6').removeAttr("disabled");
            $('#cns7').removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
            $("#cns").attr("disabled", true);
            $("#cns2").attr("disabled", true);
            $("#cns3").attr("disabled", true);
            $('#cns4').attr("disabled", true);
            $('#cns5').attr("disabled", true);
            $('#cns6').attr("disabled", true);
            $('#cns7').attr("disabled", true);
        }
    });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sccb2').click(function(){
        if (this.checked) {
            $('#cns15').removeAttr("disabled");
            $('#cns16').removeAttr("disabled");
            $('#cns17').removeAttr("disabled");
            $('#cns18').removeAttr("disabled");
            $('#cns19').removeAttr("disabled");
            $('#cns20').removeAttr("disabled");
            $('#cns21').removeAttr("disabled");

        } else {
            $("#cns15").attr("disabled", true);
            $("#cns16").attr("disabled", true);
            $("#cns17").attr("disabled", true);
            $("#cns18").attr("disabled", true);
            $("#cns19").attr("disabled", true);
            $("#cns20").attr("disabled", true);
            $("#cns21").attr("disabled", true);
        }
    });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sccb2').click(function(){
        if (this.checked) {
            $('#cns15').removeAttr("disabled");
            $('#cns16').removeAttr("disabled");
            $('#cns17').removeAttr("disabled");
            $('#cns18').removeAttr("disabled");
            $('#cns19').removeAttr("disabled");
            $('#cns20').removeAttr("disabled");
            $('#cns21').removeAttr("disabled");

        } else {
            $("#cns15").attr("disabled", true);
            $("#cns16").attr("disabled", true);
            $("#cns17").attr("disabled", true);
            $("#cns18").attr("disabled", true);
            $("#cns19").attr("disabled", true);
            $("#cns20").attr("disabled", true);
            $("#cns21").attr("disabled", true);
        }
    });
});
</script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "select" ).change(function () {
        var val = $( "select" ).val();
        if (val != 'select one') {
            var tableRows = $("table tr");
            jQuery.each(tableRows, function(i ,tr) {
                if (i > val) {
                    $(tr).hide();
                } else {
                    $(tr).show();
                }
            })
        }
      }
    )
});
</script>
  <style>
tbody tr {
display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Accordion Example</h2>
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
<fieldset>
<fieldset style="width: 1031px;"><legend style="font-weight: bold; font-family: Comic Sans MS;">Personal Details</legend><br>
<div style="width: 1021px;" class="form-group"> 
<big><label for="stuffname">Firstname<span style="color: red;">*</span></label></big>&nbsp; &nbsp;<input size="15" name="stuffname" class="input"> &nbsp;&nbsp;<big><label for="stufmname">Middlename<span style="color: red;">*</span></label></big>&nbsp;<input size="15" class="input" name="stufmname">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<big><label for="stufsname">Surname<span style="color: red;">*</span></label></big>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input size="16" class="input" name="stufsname"></div>
<br>
<big><label for="stufgender">Gender<span style="color: red;">*</span></label></big>&nbsp;
<select name="stufgender" class="input">
<option value="">-select--</option>
<option>Male</option>
<option>Mx</option>
</select>
</fieldset>
<fieldset style="width: 1012px;">
<legend><br>
<span style="font-weight: bold; font-family: Comic Sans MS;">Address
Details</span></legend>
<div style="width: 1021px;" class="form-group">
<big><label for="stufaddress">If address different than Applicant's address please tick the checkbox? <span style="color: red;">*</span></label></big>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="sccb" name="stufaddress" value="stufaddress"><br><br>
<big><label for="stufadd1">Add. Line 1<span style="color: red;">*</span></label></big>
&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" class="input" id="cns" name="stufadd1" disabled="disabled"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <big><label for="stufadd2">Add. Line 2</label></big>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" class="input" id="cns2" name="stufadd2" disabled="disabled"/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
<big><label for="stufadd3">Add. Line 3</label></big>
&nbsp;<input type="text" class="input" id="cns3" name="stufadd3" disabled="disabled" size="18"/><br>
<br>
<big><label for="stufcity">City<span style="color: red;">*</span></label></big>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input size="15" class="input" type="text" id="cns4" name="stufcity" disabled="disabled"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<big><label for="stufstate">State<span style="color: red;">*</span></label></big>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input size="15" class="input" type="text" id="cns5" name="stufstate" disabled="disabled"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<big><label for="stufcountry">Country<span style="color: red;">*</span></label></big>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input size="15" class="input" type="text" id="cns6" name="stufcountry" disabled="disabled"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <big><label for="stufpincode">Pincode<span style="color: red;">*</span></label></big>
&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; <input size="10" class="input" type="text" id="cns7" name="stufpincode" disabled="disabled"/> </div>
</fieldset>
<br style="font-family: Comic Sans MS;">
<fieldset>
<legend style="font-weight: bold; font-family: Comic Sans MS;">Qualification
Details</legend>
<div style="width: 1021px;" class="form-group"><big><big><small><label for="stufpgd">Post Graduation </label></small><label for="stufpgd"></label></big>&nbsp;</big>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input name="stufpgd" class="input">

<div style="width: 1021px;" class="form-group"><span style="color: red;">(include
University name)</span>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span style="color: red;">(include University name)</span><br>
<br>
</div>
</div>
</fieldset>
<br>
<div style="width: 1021px;" class="form-group">
<fieldset><legend style="font-family: Comic Sans MS; font-weight: bold;">Job/Business
Detail</legend>
<div style="width: 1021px;" class="form-group"><big><label for="stufcname">Company Name</label></big>
&nbsp;&nbsp; <input name="stufcname" class="input">&nbsp;
<big><label for="stufoccupation">Occupation</label></big>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; <input class="input" name="stufoccupation">
</div>
</fieldset>
</div>
</fieldset>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 2</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
<fieldset>
<fieldset style="width: 1031px;"><legend style="font-weight: bold; font-family: Comic Sans MS;">Personal Details</legend><br>
<div style="width: 1021px;" class="form-group"> <big><label for="stumtitle">Title<span style="color: red;">*</span></label></big>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
<select name="stumtitle" class="input">
<option value="">-select--</option>
<option>Mrs</option>
<option>Ms</option>
<option>Miss</option>
<option>Dr</option>
</select>
</fieldset>
<fieldset style="width: 1012px;">
<legend><br>
<span style="font-weight: bold; font-family: Comic Sans MS;">Address
Details</span></legend>
<div style="width: 1021px;" class="form-group">
<big><label for="stumaddress">If address different than Applicant's address please tick the checkbox? <span style="color: red;">*</span></label></big><big>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="sccb1" name="stumaddress" value="stumaddress"><br><br>
<label for="stumadd1">Add. Line 1<span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" id="cns8" class="input" name="stumadd1" disabled="disabled"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <label for="stumadd2">Add. Line 2</label>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" id="cns9" class="input" name="stumadd2" disabled="disabled"/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<label for="stumadd3">Add. Line 3</label>
&nbsp; <input size="18" type="text" id="cns10" class="input" name="stumadd3" disabled="disabled"/><br>
<br>
<label for="stumcity">City<span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input size="15" type="text" id="cns11" class="input" name="stumcity" disabled="disabled"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<label for="stumstate">State<span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input size="15" type="text" id="cns12" class="input" name="stumstate" disabled="disabled"/>&nbsp;
<label for="stumcountry">Country<span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input size="15" type="text" id="cns13" class="input" name="stumcountry" disabled="disabled"/>&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<label for="stumpincode">Pincode<span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; <input size="10" type="text" id="cns14" class="input" name="stumpincode" disabled="disabled"/></div>
</fieldset>
<br style="font-family: Comic Sans MS;">
<fieldset>
<legend style="font-weight: bold; font-family: Comic Sans MS;">Qualification
Details</legend>
<div style="width: 1021px;" class="form-group"><big><big><small><label for="stumpgd">Post Graduation </label></small><label for="stumpgd"></label></big>&nbsp;</big>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input name="stumpgd" class="input">
</div>
</div>
</fieldset>
<br>
<div style="width: 1021px;" class="form-group">
<fieldset><legend style="font-family: Comic Sans MS; font-weight: bold;">Job/Business
Detail</legend>
<div style="width: 1021px;" class="form-group"><big><label for="stumcname">Company Name</label></big>
&nbsp;&nbsp; <input name="stumcname" class="input">
</div>
</fieldset>
</div>
</fieldset>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Collapsible Group 3</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
<fieldset>
<fieldset style="width: 1031px;"><legend style="font-weight: bold; font-family: Comic Sans MS;">Personal Details</legend><br>
<div style="width: 1021px;" class="form-group"> <big><label for="stugtitle">Title<span style="color: red;">*</span></label></big>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
<select name="stugtitle" class="input">
<option value="">-select--</option>
<option>Mr</option>
<option>Mrs</option>
</select>
</fieldset>
<fieldset style="width: 1012px;">
<legend><br>
<span style="font-weight: bold; font-family: Comic Sans MS;">Address
Details</span></legend>
<div style="width: 1021px;" class="form-group">
<big><label for="stugaddress">If address different than Applicant's address please tick the checkbox?<span style="color: red;">*</span></label></big>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="sccb2" name="stugaddress" value="stugaddress"><br><br>
<big><label for="stugadd1">Add. Line 1<span style="color: red;">*</span></label></big>
&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" id="cns15" class="input" name="stugadd1" disabled="disabled"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<big><label for="stugadd2">Add. Line 2</label></big>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" id="cns16" class="input" name="stugadd2" disabled="disabled"/>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
<big><label for="stugadd3">Add. Line 3</label></big>
&nbsp; <input size="18" type="text" id="cns17" class="input" name="stugadd3" disabled="disabled"/><br>
<br>
<big><label for="stugcity">City<span style="color: red;">*</span></label></big>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input size="15" type="text" id="cns18" class="input" name="stugcity" disabled="disabled"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<big><label for="stugstate">State<span style="color: red;">*</span></label></big>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input size="15" type="text" id="cns19" class="input" name="stugstate" disabled="disabled"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<big><label for="stugcountry">Country<span style="color: red;">*</span></label></big>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input size="15" type="text" id="cns20" class="input" name="stugcountry" disabled="disabled"/>&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <big><label for="stugpincode">Pincode<span style="color: red;">*</span></label></big>
&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; <input size="10" type="text" id="cns21" class="input" name="stumgpincode" disabled="disabled"/></div>
</fieldset>
<br style="font-family: Comic Sans MS;">
<fieldset>
<legend style="font-weight: bold; font-family: Comic Sans MS;">Qualification
Details</legend>
<div style="width: 1021px;" class="form-group"><big><big><small><label for="stugpgd">Post Graduation </label></small><label for="stugpgd"></label></big>&nbsp;</big>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input name="stugpgd" class="input">
<big><label for="stuggd">Graduation</label></big>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; <input class="input" name="stuggd">
&nbsp; &nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<big><label for="stug12">12th Marks/Grade</label></big>
&nbsp; <input size="10" class="input" name="stug12"><br>
<div style="width: 1021px;" class="form-group"><span style="color: red;">(include
University name)</span>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span style="color: red;">(include University name)</span><br>
<br>
<big><label for="stugpq">Profesional Qualification</label></big>
&nbsp;
<input name="stugpq" class="input">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<big><label for="stug10">10th Mark/Grade</label></big> &nbsp; &nbsp; <input size="10" class="input" name="stug10">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<big><label for="stugalumni">School Alumni?</label></big>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
<select name="stugalumni" class="input">
<option value="">-select--</option>
<option>Yes</option>
<option>No
</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
</fieldset>
<br>
<div style="width: 1021px;" class="form-group">
<fieldset><legend style="font-family: Comic Sans MS; font-weight: bold;">Job/Business
Detail</legend>
<div style="width: 1021px;" class="form-group"><big><label for="stugcname">Company Name</label></big>
&nbsp;&nbsp; <input name="stugcname" class="input">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<big><label for="stugoccupation">Occupation</label></big>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; <input class="input" name="stugoccupation">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp; &nbsp;
<big><label for="stugdesignation">Designation</label></big>
&nbsp;&nbsp; <input size="18" class="input" name="stugdesignation"><br>
<br>
<big><label for="stugcadd1">Add. Line 1</label></big>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; <input name="stugcadd1" class="input">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
<big><label for="stugcadd2">Add. Line 2</label></big>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; <input class="input" name="stugcadd2">&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
<big><label style="font-weight: bold;" for="stugcadd3">Add. Line 3</label></big>
&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; <input size="16" class="input" name="stugcadd3"><br>
<br>
<big><label for="stugccity">City</label></big>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input size="15" name="stugccity" class="input">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp; &nbsp;
<big><label for="stugcstate">State</label></big>
&nbsp;&nbsp; <input size="15" class="input" name="stugcstate">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp; &nbsp;
<big><label for="stugcpincode">Pincode</label></big>
&nbsp; <input size="15" class="input" name="stugcpincode">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<big><label for="stugdoj">Joining Date</label></big>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input class="input" name="stugdoj" size="15" type="date">
</div>
</fieldset>
</div>
</fieldset>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse4">Sibling Detail</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">



<big style="font-family: Comic Sans MS;"><big>Select Number of siblings<span
style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">*</span></big></big><span
style="font-family: Comic Sans MS;"> </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<select name="app_siblingno" class="input">
<option>select one</option>
<option>0</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>6</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<table style="text-align: left; width: 100px;" border="0"
cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="6" rowspan="1" style="vertical-align: top;">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align: top;">S.No 1
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Name&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="app_siblingname1">
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Birthdate<input name="app_siblingdob1">
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Class<select name="app_siblingclass1">
<option>select one</option>

</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Gender<select name="app_siblinggender1">
<option>select one</option>
<option>Male</option>
<option>Female</option>
<option>Mx</option>
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;School Name<input name="app_schlname1">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align: top;">2
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="app_siblingname2">
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="app_siblingdob2">
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><select name="app_siblingclass2">
<option>select one</option>
<option>XII</option>

</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><select name="app_siblinggender2">
<option>select one</option>
<option>Male</option>
<option>Female</option>
<option>Mx</option>
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="app_siblingschlname2">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align: top;">3
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="app_siblingname3">
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="app_siblingdob3">
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><select name="app_siblingclass3">
<option>select one</option>
<option>XII</option>
<option>XI</option>
<option>X</option>
<option>IX</option>

</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><select name="app_siblinggender3">
<option>select one</option>
<option>Male</option>
<option>Female</option>
<option>Mx</option>
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="app_siblingschlname3">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align: top;">4
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="app_siblingname4">
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="app_siblingdob4">
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><select name="app_siblingclass4">
<option>select one</option>
<option>XII</option>
<option>XI</option>
<option>X</option>
<option>IX</option>
<option>VIII</option>
<option>VII</option>
<option>VI</option>
<option>V</option>
<option>IV</option>
<option>III</option>
<option>II</option>
<option>I</option>
<option>KG/Prep</option>
<option>Nursery</option>
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><select name="app_siblinggender4">
<option>select one</option>
<option>Male</option>
<option>Female</option>
<option>Mx</option>
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="app_siblingschlname4">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align: top;">5
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="app_siblingname5">
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="app_siblingdob5">
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><select name="app_siblingclass5">
<option>select one</option>
<option>XII</option>
<option>XI</option>
<option>X</option>
<option>IX</option>

</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><select name="app_siblinggender5">
<option>select one</option>
<option>Male</option>
<option>Female</option>
<option>Mx</option>
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="app_siblingschlname5">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align: top;">6
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="app_siblingname6">
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="app_siblingdob6">
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><select name="app_siblingclass6">
<option>select one</option>
<option>XII</option>
<option>XI</option>
<option>X</option>
<option>IX</option>

</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><select name="app_siblinggender6">
<option>select one</option>
<option>Male</option>
<option>Female</option>
<option>Mx</option>
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="app_siblingschlname6">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse5">Document Upload</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse5" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
        Document Upload
(Only PDF/JPE/JPEG)</span></big></big></label></big><big><br>
</big><big>
</big><big><span style="color: red;">(Note : File size
should not be more than 100KB)</span></big><big><br>
</big><big>
</big><big><br>
</big><big>
</big><div class="form-group"><big>
</big><big><big></div><big>
</big><big><br>
</big><big>
</big>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have to strip few fields out of the code because of word restrictons.Please help me how to make this works as expected....

Comment: It seems like you may have stripped out some important fields, I can't seem to find the fields with the ids you reference in the javascript.

Comment: Also, the second and third blocks of javascript you have appear to be identical, is that a mistake?

Comment: Thanks @simonv for pointing that out. I have now managed to get the javascript working. But Jquery is still not working(its in the section 4). https://jsfiddle.net/53nfxxdw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have managed to get this working by eliminating multiple jqueries and replacing them with one with the latest version of 2.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/external-resources)? I think you could accomplish this a lot easier and more succinctly using ngDisabled, ngShow, and [ngIf](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) attributes on your html elements.

AngularJS attempts to minimize the impedance mismatch between document centric HTML and what an application needs by creating new HTML constructs.

Comment: Hi @Randy Daddis I have never used Angular JS. Can you throw some light on it ?

Comment: I have been using AngularJS for almost a year now. Although there is a learning curve, it has saved me countless hours in time. AngularJS has enabled me to write more concise code and to eliminate most DOM manipulation. I suggest that you check out YouTube videos about AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer not using jQuery for ready events, but the standard

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    // do stuff
})
```

instead. With this multiple load event listeners will add up and not interfere with each other. Also you avoid the need for jQuery to be loaded before you use a $(document).ready() - if you load jQuery after this it won't work anyways.

**EDIT:**
I was wrong, only window.onload will override if you use multiple instances, $(document).ready() will stack up. But you need jQuery to be loaded in advance.